# What is this format in ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax

In a book they showed me this declaration:

```
friends = [ { first_name: "Emily", last_name: "Laskin" }, { first_name: "Nick", last_name: "Mauro" }, { first_name: "Mark", last_name: "Maxwell" } ]
```

This doesn't look like a hash. And when I enter it in IRB i get an error.

What is this format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an array of hashes, written in the Ruby 1.9 hash syntax.

```
{ first_name: "Emily", last_name: "Laskin" }
```

is equivalent to:

```
{ :first_name => "Emily", :last_name => "Laskin" }
```

Answer (score 4):

The `{key: value}` syntax is new in 1.9 and is equivalent to `{:key => value}`.

Answer (score 4):

It is an array of hashes, only the hashes are 1.9 style hashes.